# Remove files which have not filename duplicates

Tags: php, json, file, scandir

For each document (.pdf, .txt, .docx ecc) I have also a corresponding json file with the same filename.

Example:
file1.json,
file1.pdf,
file2.json,
file2.txt,
filex.json,
filex.pdf,

But I got also some json files which are not accompanied with the corresponding document.

I want to delete all json files which have no corresponding document. Im really stucked because I cant find a proper solution to my problem.

I know how to scandir() get the filename, extensions from pathinfo() ecc. but the issue is that for each json file I find in directory I have to perform another foreach on that directory excluding all json files and see If the same filename exists or not so than I can decide to delete it. (This is how I think to solve it).

The problem here is with performance since there are millions of files and for each json I have to run a foreach on millions of files.

Can anyone guide me to a better solution?

Thank you!

Edit: Since no one will help without first posting a piece of code (and this approach in stackoverflow is definitively wrong) here is how I'm trying.:

```
<?php

$dir = "2000/";

$files = scandir($dir);

foreach ($files as $file) {

    $fullName = pathinfo($file);

    if ($fullName['extension'] === 'json') {
        if (!in_array($fullName['filename'].'.pdf', $files)){
            unlink($dir.$file);
        }
    }
}
```

Now as you can see I can only search only for one type of document (`.pdf` in this case). I want to search for every extension excluding `.json` and also I don't want that for each json file to run a foreach/in_array() but achieving all this in just one foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should consider it in another way? I mean, iterate through all files, and try to find corresponding files to `json`, if not found remove it.

It would look like follows:

```
$dir = "2000/";

foreach (glob($dir . "*.json") as $file) {
    $file = new \SplFileInfo($dir . $file);
    if (count(glob($dir . $file->getBasename('.' . $file->getExtension()) . ".*")) === 1) {
        unlink($dir . $file->getFilename());
    }
}
```

---

**Manual**

[PHP: SplFileInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php)

[PHP: glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: This is the case when document exist but json doesn't and this way we can remove only the document since we delete the $file iteration which will not have `.json` extension. My case is to remove json when no corresponding document.

Comment: I've updated my answer :) It should work. I'm unable to run it now, so please check if my syntax is valid, if not please let me know :)

Comment: Just one problem. `$file->getFilename()` will get the filename and extension. The working case would be `$file->getBasename('.' . $file->getExtension())`.
Edit the answer so I can accept it! I had not tried yet...

Comment: and maybe `unlink($dir . $file);`

Comment: Yes thank you for showing me another approach on solving it. I like it!

Comment: Thank you :) I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Ok now I was on front on my pc and give it a try. Please consider on making another edit on the answer. Since `$file` is now a new object we cannot directly unlink it. 
So it would be `unlink($dir . $file->getFilename());`

Comment: Does it work with `unlink($file->getPathname())` ?